# TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'checked') in javascript

Tags: javascript

```html
<article id="mission">
    <img src="https://blog.kakaocdn.net/dn/TfNOJ/btqNXGzXt1z/1Zlb8W1gitIt6WOPWS7z3k/img.gif" width="100%" />
  </article>

  <article id="container">
    <button></button>
  
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </article>

  <script src="./main.js"></script>
```

```js
let inputlist = document.querySelectorAll('input');
let button = document.querySelector('button');

let save = 0;
    
let num = 0;
button.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    for(let i = 0; i< 4; i++){
        inputlist[(i+save)%14].checked = true;
        
 
    }

    num++;

    if(save-1 != -1){
        if(inputlist[(save-1)%14].checked == true){
            inputlist[(save-1)%14].checked =false;
        }
    
    }

    save++;

});
```

When I run the code, it doesn't work any more than 7-8 clicks.
When you enter the link in the body, the first input element should behave like the image that appears.

But I get the error TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'checked') and it doesn't work anymore.

Why?

Comment: You only have 13 checkboxes (indexes 0 to 12). Using `% 14` can result in out-of-bounds errors

Comment: what exactly you want to do

Comment: _`save-1 != -1`_ aka `save !== 0`

Answer (score 0):

You have 13 inputs so it should be mod 13 not 14.
Check the snippet below

```js
let inputlist = document.querySelectorAll('input');
let button = document.querySelector('button');

let save = 0;
    
let num = 0;
button.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        inputlist[(i + save) % 13].checked = true;
    }

    num++;

    if(save - 1 !== -1){
        if(inputlist[(save - 1) % 13].checked === true){
            inputlist[(save - 1) % 13].checked = false;
        }
    }

    save++;
});
```

```html
<article id="mission">
    <img src="https://blog.kakaocdn.net/dn/TfNOJ/btqNXGzXt1z/1Zlb8W1gitIt6WOPWS7z3k/img.gif" width="100%" />
  </article>

  <article id="container">
    <button>Move</button>
  
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </article>
```

Comment: thanks....... very much. your comment is very easy for me !!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you're using %14, but you only have 12 input elements on the page. When the code is running through the loop you run out of elements. The solution is to either change your %14 to %12 or to add in an additional two input elements.

The other option if you're going to add checkboxes would be to use %inputlist.length. This would avoid needing to count how many input elements in your html file.

Comment: thanks a lot! your specific comment is very helpful for me :)